# WooCommerce recent products exclude hidden products from displaying using recent_products shortcode

Tags: php, wordpress

I’m trying to exclude a hidden product from the WooCommerce recent products shortcode by writing the following php code using a code snippet plugin but the empty product box still appears. Basically I was able to hide a product but recent products is still displaying an empty area of where the product used to be instead of replacing it with the next recent product. Here is my code but it seems to not be working.

```
<?php
function exclude_hidden_product( $should_index, $id ) {
    $product_id_to_exclude = array(9872);

         if (in_array($id,$product_id_to_hide) && !empty(wc_memberships_get_user_active_memberships())) {
              $should_index = false;
         }
    return $should_index;
}

add_filter( ‘storefront_homepage_after_recent_products’,’exclude_hidden_product’, 10, 2);
```

Comment: You are using wrong hook. 
storefront_recent_products_args – filter the homepage recent products arguments
storefront_recent_products_shortcode_args – filter the homepage recent products shortcode arguments . Read more here - https://woocommerce.com/document/storefront-hooks-actions-filters/

Comment: Martin, do you know how to exclude the product from recent products using the storefront_recent_products_args and how would you apply the storefront_recent_products_shortcode_args hook ? Thanks.